# Do I need MSAS12 or MSRS12 with SQL Server 2016 installed

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to clean up the Microsoft SQL Server folder. I've upgraded to SQL Server 2016. I did not use any reporting in SQL Server 2014. Can I delete the `MSAS12` or `MSRS12` folders?

Comment: There's no such thing as MSSQL 13. There's 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, and 2016. No 13 anywhere in there.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I'm *assuming* he means SQL Server v13.x --> SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear which folders you exactly mean. SSRS and SSAS have several folders.

However, generally I would answer like this:

While you clearly could uninstall those features (and stand-alone software) via SQL Server Installation Center (always first choice) or Software/Features in the Windows Control Panel (second choice, if SQL Server Installation Center does not apply), I would not just delete those folders directly. If they were not removed after an installation, then it could be very dangerous to delete them. They do not use much space after you've uninstalled the software, so it's no big deal to leave them there.

This may be a different story of course, if a folder in question contains database/backup files for those databases. In that case you need to decide whether or not you want to keep those files. I'd at least backup those files before deleting, unless you're rally sure that you'll use them never again.

Comment: MSSQL13 is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Express and the only SQL server installed after Windows Update made system unstable and I was forced to Reset my PC.